# Get the date (a day before current time) in Bash

Tags: bash, unix, date, solaris

How can I print the date which is a day before current time in Bash?

Comment: Tried date but seems like there is no -d switch in Solaris 10's bash

Comment: I found another great solution by installing gnu date (coreutil package) from sunfreeware.

Comment: nor is there a -d switch in AIX's date

Comment: The `--date` or `-d` option is only available in GNU date

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15374752/462865 for a DST-safe version of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry not mentioning I on Solaris system.
As such, the -date switch is not available on Solaris bash.

I find out I can get the previous date with little trick on timezone.

```
DATE=`TZ=MYT+16 date +%Y-%m-%d_%r`
echo $DATE
```

Comment: This method is not 100% reliable (about 98% actually) if you happen to live in a place using daylight saving time.

Comment: Not exactly, you can use 

```bash
$(TZ=America/New_York date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21283578/2089784 for a DST-safe version

Answer (score 322):

if you have GNU date and i understood you correctly

```
$ date +%Y:%m:%d -d "yesterday"
2009:11:09
```

or

```
$ date +%Y:%m:%d -d "1 day ago"
2009:11:09
```

Comment: I found most are as suggested answer but -d switch is not found in Solaris's date

Comment: For the usage on Ubuntu with date function: $(date +%Y:%m:%d -d "1 day ago"), output is:
2013:04:21.
And if you want the date 10 days before, you can use

$(date +%Y:%m:%d -d "10 days ago")
or

$(date +%Y:%m:%d -d "10 day ago")

Comment: On OS X you can install coreutils through brew: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15374752/get-yesterdays-date-in-bash-on-linux-dst-safe#comment35873979_22374082

Comment: `date -v-1d` on OSX (minus), `-v+1d` (plus)

Comment: This bash function will work on both Linux and OSX. Basically it tries the GNU Linux style first. If that fails it tries the OSX style. Call it with an argument of the number of days in the past you want the date. If you pass no argument it assume 0 days. This code is a one-liner, so cut and paste should work -- no line endings assumed.
`date_days_past () { days_past=${1:-0}; if ! date -v-${days_past}d +%Y%m%d 2>/dev/null; then date --date="-${days_past} day" +%Y%m%d; fi }`

Comment: For Solaris, use one time timezone
```bash
 $(TZ=America/New_York date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

Comment: date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%F' is shorter

Answer (score 62):

If you have BSD (OSX) `date` you can do it like this:

```
date -j -v-1d
Wed Dec 14 15:34:14 CET 2011
```

Or if you want to do date calculations on an arbitrary date:

```
date -j -v-1d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2011-09-01" "+%Y-%m-%d"
2011-08-31
```

Answer (score 50):

```
date --date='-1 day'
```

Comment: Erros on macOS Sierra: `date: illegal option -- -`

Comment: You need to install the GNU version of `date`, available through the `coreutils` package, to make this syntax work on macOS. If you're using Homebrew, you can install it via `brew install coreutils`, after which you should be able to use GNU date through the `gdate` command. See: https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 30):

**MAC OSX**

For yesterday's date:

```
date -v-1d +%F
```

where **1d** defines current day minus 1 day. Similarly,

**date -v-1w +%F** - for previous week date

**date -v-1m +%F** - for previous month date

**IF YOU HAVE GNU DATE,**

```
date --date="1 day ago"
```

More info: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-get-yesterdays-tomorrows-date.html

Answer (score 8):

[Advanced Bash-scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html)

```
date +%Y:%m:%d -d "yesterday"
```

For details about the date format see the man page for [date](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html)

```
date --date='-1 day'
```

Answer (score 8):

Well this is a late answer,but this seems to work!!

```
     YESTERDAY=`TZ=GMT+24 date +%d-%m-%Y`;
     echo $YESTERDAY;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

or

```
date=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d')
echo $date
```

Comment: That results in `date: illegal option: -d` on Solaris.  Your answer that relies on non-portable GNU extensions to [the POSIX-standard `date` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) for a question about the non-GNU Solaris  platform.

Answer (score 4):

```
date --date='-1 day'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use Perl instead perhaps?

```
perl -e 'print scalar localtime( time - 86400 ) . "\n";'
```

Or, use nawk and (ab)use /usr/bin/adb:

```
nawk 'BEGIN{printf "0t%d=Y\n", srand()-86400}' | adb
```

Came across [this](http://solarisjedi.blogspot.com/2006/06/solaris-date-command-and-epoch-time.html) too ... insane!

```
/usr/bin/truss /usr/bin/date 2>&1 | nawk -F= '/^time\(\)/ {gsub(/ /,"",$2);printf "0t%d=Y\n", $2-86400}' | adb
```

Answer (score 3):

Not very sexy but might do the job:

```
perl -e 'my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time - 86400);$year += 1900; $mon+= 1; printf ("YESTERDAY: %04d%02d%02d \n", $year, $mon, $mday)'
```

Formated from "martin clayton" answer.

Answer (score 3):

short answer (GNU format):

```
date +%Y-%m-%d -d "-2 day"
```

if you are using OSX, but you need create for GNU compatible, install coreutils first

```
brew install coreutils
```

then edit your profile with:

```
#gnu coreutils first
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

re-start your terminal, and now you able to use GNU format!

Answer (score 2):

You could do a simple calculation, pimped with an regex, if the chosen date format is 'YYYYMM':

```
echo $(($(date +"%Y%m") - 1)) | sed -e 's/99$/12/'
```

In January of 2020 it will return 201912 ;-)
But, it's only a workaround, when date does not have calculation options and other dateinterpreter options (e.g. using perl) not available ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
OFFSET=1;
eval `date "+day=%d; month=%m; year=%Y"`
# Subtract offset from day, if it goes below one use 'cal'
# to determine the number of days in the previous month.
day=`expr $day - $OFFSET`
if [ $day -le 0 ] ;then
month=`expr $month - 1`
if [ $month -eq 0 ] ;then
year=`expr $year - 1`
month=12
fi
set `cal $month $year`
xday=${$#}
day=`expr $xday + $day`
fi
echo $year-$month-$day
```

Comment: +1 for correction, interesting method, even though it's a bit verbose.

Comment: Hi medoix, I am not able to find the meaning of ${$#}. I know that $# stands for the number of arguments to a script/function. But I am not able to relate to this. Please help.

Comment: This doesn't work for the previus day on change of month . For example today is `1 July , 2013` , the result being printed out is `2013-6-1347`, whereas the expected result is `2013-6-30`

Comment: Instead of the 3 lines between the "fi" try "day=`echo $(cal $month $year)|tr ' ' '\n'|tail -n 1`"

Answer (score 1):

```
yesterday=`date -d "-1 day" %F`
```

Puts yesterday's date in YYYY-MM-DD format into variable `$yesterday`.

Answer (score 1):

DST aware solution:

Manipulating the Timezone is possible for changing the clock some hours. Due to the daylight saving time, 24 hours ago can be today or the day before yesterday.

You are sure that yesterday is 20 or 30 hours ago. Which one? Well, the most recent one that is not today.

```
echo -e "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)\n$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

The -e parameter used in the echo command is needed with bash, but will not work with ksh. In ksh you can use the same command without the -e flag.

When your script will be used in different environments, you can start the script with #!/bin/ksh or #!/bin/bash. You could also replace the \n by a newline:

```
echo "$(TZ=GMT+30 date +%Y-%m-%d)
$(TZ=GMT+20 date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep -v $(date +%Y-%m-%d) | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code , which takes care of the DST part as well.

```
if [ $(date +%w) -eq $(date -u +%w) ]; then
  tz=$(( 10#$gmthour - 10#$localhour ))
else
  tz=$(( 24 - 10#$gmthour + 10#$localhour ))
fi
echo $tz
myTime=`TZ=GMT+$tz date +'%Y%m%d'`
```

Courtsey [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17414842/392233)

Answer (score 0):

For my case I needed a portable solution to get the number of seconds since the epoch one hour ago, and this worked on both ubuntu and macOS:

```bash
$(( $(date +%s) - 3600 ))
```

Explaining this:

- `$(( ))` is doing an arithmetic expansion
- `date +%s` seems to be a portable way to get seconds since epoch
- 3600 seconds in an hour

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
date +%Y:%m:%d|awk -vFS=":" -vOFS=":" '{$3=$3-1;print}'
2009:11:9
```

Comment: What about if today is the 1st January?