# Arithmetic error - calculation taking base as 8

Tags: bash, date-arithmetic, octal

I am executing the following piece of code. I am not sure why the calculation is happening in octal? How can I make this code better?

```
#!/bin/bash
gmthour=$(date -u +%H)
localhour=$(date +%H)
echo $gmthour
echo $localhour
tz=$(( gmthour - localhour ))
echo $tz
```

Error

```
22
08
MyFile.ksh: line 6: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
```

Comment: can't duplicate this issue , what version of bash ?

Comment: Mine is bash-3.00 . I guess whether you get or not get the issue wuilll depend on whether the localhour/gmthour has leading zero or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leading zero is what causes the number to be interpreted as octal. Quote from `man bash`:

> **ARITHMETIC EVALUATION**
>   [...]
>   Constants with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal numbers. A leading 0x or 0X denotes hexadecimal. Otherwise, numbers take the form [base#]n, where the optional base is a decimal number between 2 and 64 representing the arithmetic base, and n is a number in that base. If base# is omitted, then base 10 is used.

Change the format string of the `date` commands to `%k` or `%_H` to get rid of leading zeroes:

```
#!/bin/bash
gmthour=$(date -u +%k)
localhour=$(date +%k)
echo $gmthour
echo $localhour
tz=$(( gmthour - localhour ))
echo $tz
```

Beware that your calculation will break when the day changes. Example:

```
$ date
Di 2. Jul 00:50:29 CEST 2013
$ gmthour=$(date -u +%k)
$ localhour=$(date +%k)
$ echo $gmthour
22
$ echo $localhour
0
$ echo $((gmthour - localhour))
22
```

CEST clearly isn't UTC+22.

Try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
gmthour=$(date -u +%k)
localhour=$(date +%k)
echo $gmthour
echo $localhour
if [ $(date +%w) -eq $(date -u +%w) ]; then
  tz=$(( gmthour - localhour ))
else
  tz=$(( 24 - gmthour + localhour ))
fi
echo $tz
```

Comment: how would it break . Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
tz=$(( 10#$gmthour - 10#$localhour ))
```

> I am not sure why the calculation is happening in octal

Just because when there's a leading zero, the number is interpreted as being in radix 8. To prevent that, you can impose the shell to interpret number in radix 10 with `10#`. But seeing your comment, let me stress that in this case you must explicitly use the dollar sign.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Already tried doing that , get `MyFile.ksh: line 6: 10#gmthour: value too great for base (error token is "10#gmthour")`

Comment: @misguided Watch the dollar signs!

Comment: thanks mate. Missed out the dollar sign as specified , while trying the code . Onc ethe sign is back on . The issue is fixed.